# When the database grows it tends to run slower?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

We have a simple question here: we are performing many inserts in some tables (MySql Database) to test our services. So, after many inserts, the services has become slower. We can conclude (as a initial step) that when the database grows it tends to run slower?

Comment: Sounds like lack of, or poor use of, indexes

Answer (score 1):

No, not if you make proper use of indexes and your hard drives aren't made of mashed potato.

Does it become a consideration? Yes.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of slowdown is very common in newly rolled-out software. As the database grows, you discover the query bottlenecks. Part of rolling out new software is tuning your database as you gain experience.  It's not MySQL's fault. It's just the nature of database applications.

(Lots of new development teams learn this lesson the hard way when they fail to budget and staff for this tuning task. I hope you're not in that category, because I have been there and I know it stinks.)

You need to figure out how to tell which queries are running slowly in production.  You can use the slow query log to do this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html

Then you need to examine the worst-offending queries. You will probably discover an opportunity to create some indexes to accelerate them.

It's a good idea to keep doing this for the first few weeks of each new rollout.

Something else you can do is optimize your fastest-growing tables once in a while.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html

(This sort of thing requires a bit of downtime).

Congratulations on creating a software application that's scaling up!

Answer (score 0):

As I see it's not about having lots of tables but the table design and other works inner MySQL. If that would be the situation common brands such as Google - Yahoo wouldn't be delivering a great performance.

Comment: To be fair they put a _tremendous_ quantity of resources into their systems to allow them to scale like they do.

Comment: You mean the BigTable?

Comment: I mean the tens of thousands of servers distributed across the globe with more redundancy than even the worst pun